# How do I get the height of the navigationbar in a child view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation controller-based UI which contains a view

```
MainView
```

The MainView contains a child view

```
MainView
  ChildView
```

and the ChildView contains a subview

```
MainView
  ChildView
    SubView
```

When I push the ChildView onto the stack, I need to get the height of the navigationbar in the SubViewController to resize some content. In SubViewController I have tried

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
```

and

```
self.parentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
```

and neither contains the height of the navigationbar. I would prefer to get the height rather than hard-code a value of 44.0.

Comment: This line works for me when I tried.
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
But not the other one.  It is a float value.

Comment: I edited the question to better reflect the situation. Does it work now for you?

Comment: The first one still worked (44.0).  But not the second one (0.00).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do it in the method `viewDidLoad`. You need to wait till all UI components are loaded when you get the dimensions. (This is just my guess.)